# Output result from Bundle Exec Rails C to a file/csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, output, bundler

Just curious if I can somehow output say an array into a .csv file from the bundle exec rails c (or console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good combination of [the CSV CLASS](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and the [rails runner commands](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) should do the trick.

Comment: Good links thank-you! For my situation I simply used the CSV class within the console for writing to a file and it worked out :)